# How to get configured email username and password from iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have created a sample iPhone application. In that application I have to fetch configured email username and password.

I have configured my GMail account in iPhone mail application.

How can i get my username and password using iPhone API.

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't fetch email configuration of iOS devices. It's not really possible with the current API, and it's better that way I think (because of privacy issues).

If you want to send emails with on your application without the user's credentials use [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).